# Maven Release plugin, version plugins and snapshots

Tags: maven, snapshot, versions, maven-release-plugin, multiple-projects

I am trying to automate the release of interdependent projects. Here is the scenario. I have two projects: A and B. Project B has a dependency on project A. Here are the steps that need to happen in the automated procedure:

1. Release project A using maven-release-plugin. ( I know how to do this). Here is the sequence of goals I have defined:
   **release:clean release:prepare -DcommitByProject=true -DautoVersionSubmodules=true release:perform**
2. Deploy the latest SNAPSHOT version of project A to the repository. (Using simply deploy is working. However there is a slight catch, which I've described below.)
3. Update the SNAPSHOT dependency version of project A in project B to the latest release version before doing a full  release. In order to achieve this I've set the **preparationGoals** like this (**clean verify versions:use-latest-versions versions:commit**) in project B's POM file.

Everything seems to work fine.

Now what I want is that once the release is complete, Project A dependency in Project B to the latest SNAPSHOT version that was set during the release by the **release:prepare** plugin.

The solution I came up with was to do a **maven deploy** for project A SNAPSHOT right after the **release:perform** was executed. (New goal sequence for project A:  **release:clean release:prepare -DcommitByProject=true -DautoVersionSubmodules=true release:perform clean install deploy**)

Then, I can execute a **versions:use-next-snapshots** at the end of the project B's release cycle.
(New goal sequence for project B: **release:clean release:prepare -DcommitByProject=true -DautoVersionSubmodules=true release:perform versions:use-next-snapshots**). Here I do restrict my versions plugin to handle only Project A dependencies.

The trouble is that when I execute the goals for Project A. Maven deploys the SNAPSHOT with the old version and not the incremented version. So if version before release for project A was **1.1-SNAPSHOT**. The version after release is now **1.2-SNAPSHOT**. The release version will be **1.1**. However, project A snapshot version deployed is **1.1-SNAPSHOT**  and not **1.2-SNAPSHOT**.

I am guessing that maven is not updating the pom in memory after the maven-release-plugin goals are executed.

Answer (score 1):

have you considered making both projects belong to a parent project. then you release the parent project which in turn releases each module (sub project) automatically